# How to remove stuck CV joint from axle?

Tags: accord, cv-joint

I am trying remove the outer CV joint from my axle (1988 Accord). I've removed the axle from the car, removed the old CV boot and have positioned it in a vice. I've tried hammering and hammering the joint but it just won't budge.

There is no Circlip or C-clip visible from the outside I can remove.

I'm honestly worried I am going to break the CV joint at this point - I've hammered so hard there are little dents in my hammer.

Would anyone know how I could remove this? What other options are there?

Comment: Bigger hammer or arrange a method to pull on it as well as the circlip can be internal

Comment: Which part is held in the vice?  Where are you hitting? Can you add a photo?

Comment: If you've hit it that hard you may have damaged it.

Comment: @HandyHowie the axle it's self is in the vice. I am hitting from the inside of the joint out (so striking from the axle side). Basically I am copy from this video here https://youtu.be/-S-ofMoWsr0?t=238

Comment: Are you able to hit on different points around the circumference, to achieve a "wiggle" effect? Is there enough flat area to really pound that hammer? If not, a solid flat bar can be held against the CV flange (wear gloves) so you have a bigger area to really swing and hit.

Comment: What I do is open the vice just enough for the axle to slide side to side, then move the axle in so that the CV joint is far way from the vice jaws, and pull it slamming the cv joint against the vice jaws, may take a few whacks to unseat the inner snap ring.

Comment: @JohnCanon yes I rotate it and have hit it at a number of angles. I've also held a block of wood across it for a bigger surface area.

Comment: A block of wood has give and will absorb some of the energy of the hit.. Find a piece of metal about 1 inch by 2 inch by 1 foot. Don't hold it like a punch. Hold it flat-wise by one end, and press the other end against the recess where you want to force to be. Hit the metal hard repeatedly on the flat end. If you have a Hilti or Bosch electric impact hammer, then a flat punch bit (half-inch diameter) would work.